# One liner to create array list which shows initial size to be 100

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to create an array list such that when I print ArrayList.size(), I want it to display 100 or some other large number.

*Scenario*
It's for a program where I'm trying to find the minimum size of array list that fits a condition. So I want the initial value of the ArrayList to be large, so that it keeps getting over-written by a smaller combination.

Similarly to a program to find the smallest number where you initialize the variable smallest to a large number so that it gets over-written in a linear traversal.

EDIT : This is the question I am trying to solve
To find the minimum number of coins of denomination 3 and 5 to make change of 4. Yes, it should basically return that it's not possible.

I have done this correctly if the question is only to find the number of coins

```
public class FindCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int coins = fun(4);
        if(coins == 999)    
            System.out.println("Not possible to make change with this denomination");
        else 
            System.out.println(coins);
    }

    static int fun(int n)
    {   
        if(n == 0)
            return 0;

        int ret1 = 999;
        int ret2 = 999;

        if(n >= 3)
        {
            int rec1 = fun(n-3);
            if(rec1 != 999) 
                ret1 = 1+rec1;
        }

        if(n >= 5)
        {
            int rec2 = fun(n-5);
            if(rec2 != 999) 
                ret2 = 1+rec2;
        }

        int totalret = min(ret1, ret2);

        return totalret;
    }

    static int min(int a, int b)
    {
        return a<b?a:b;
    }
}
```

Note that above, I have used a variable called totalret which, if 999, I can use it to declare that it's not possible to achieve this result.

However, if I'm asked to print the elements required instead of just finding count, the program goes wrong if there is any path where it's not possible to make change. This is because, here totalret is initialized to null and not to a large ArrayList of say 999 elements, as in the program above.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PrintSequence
{
    static int[] options = {3,5};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        result = fun(4);
        for(int i = 0;i<result.size();i++)
            System.out.print(result.get(i));
    }

    static ArrayList<Integer> fun(int n)
    {       
        int smallest = 999;
        ArrayList<Integer> totalret = null;
        for(int i = 0;i<options.length;i++)
        {
            if(n-options[i] >= 0)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> reci = fun(n-options[i]);
                ArrayList<Integer> reti = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                reti.addAll(reci);
                reti.add(0,options[i]);

                if(reti.size() < smallest)
                {
                    totalret = reti;
                    smallest = reti.size();
                }
            }
        }

        if(totalret == null)
            totalret = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        return totalret;
    }
}
```

Please suggest how I can edit the printing program to print that this is not possible.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. What is the larger picture ? What is the problem you are solving ?

Comment: @Dici, hold on a second please. Will post the edit.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: @Dici, please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

One-liner to create an `ArrayList` of size 100:

```
new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(new Object[100]))
```

**Update**

Replace both `Object` with any suitable (non-primitive) type.

If you don't need it to be an `ArrayList`, but just a `List` that cannot change size, the following is good (showing for `String` as an example):

```
Arrays.asList(new String[100])
```

Comment: This will say goodbye to type-safety and is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @MickMnemonic You can replace Object with whichever type is suitable for you.

Comment: Fair enough; that's a valid suggestion. The question is still a bit unclear, hopefully OP will clarify it so that we know the real requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I went by title and first paragraph. My one-liner fits that perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, though it is not a one liner.

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[100]; 
ArrayList arr  = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
int size = arr.size();
System.out.println(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. If you have to use an ArrayList, the only way that I can think of initializing its size would be to fill it up with "dummy" values i.e. loop and add some value up to a certain Nth size. Would that be okay/feasible in your case?

Of course, if anyone else has a better solution, feel free to comment.

Comment: Hmm, reconsidering my vote. Didn't fully get the question

Comment: Hi! Do you mean ... new ArrayList<Integer>(some_capacity) ? If so, that still only creates an empty list but with a limited amount of elements that can be added into it. Or did I misunderstand your statement?

Comment: You're right that's what I meant, but I just re-read the answer, and he wants `size` to return 100, to creating a list with a 100 items capacity. I'm reading it more carfully now to see if it makes sense

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is can help you.

```
Integer[] is = new Integer[100 + new Random().nextInt(500)];
Arrays.fill(is, 0);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(is);
```

Comment: OP asked for ArrayList, and I doubt the "or some other large number" was a reference to being random, just instead was meant as some other particular number.